# Android - reflection interface not called

Tags: android, reflection, interface, in-app-billing

This is the normal way of creating a ServiceConnection interface. If I do it this way everything works fine.

```
  ServiceConnection mServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {

        }
    };
```

But if I define a ServiceConnection interface using reflection like below then the only method ever called is `hashCode()`.

```
ServiceConnection mServiceConnection = (ServiceConnection) java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(
    ServiceConnection.class.getClassLoader(),
    new java.lang.Class[] { ServiceConnection.class },
    new java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler() {

        @Override
        public Object invoke(Object proxy, java.lang.reflect.Method method, Object[] args) throws java.lang.Throwable {
            log("methodName", method.getName());
            return null;
        }
});
```

The usage is this:

```
applicationContext.bindService(serviceIntent, mServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

What am I doing wrong here?

### UPDATE

Ok this is very weird...I used debugger and on `the line bindService()` the debugger showed that mServiceConnection is null while in the previous line i wrote `log(Boolean.toString(mServiceConnection == null))` and it printed false (!!??!!). Then I changed the return value of invoke method to return 1;

```
@Override
public Object invoke(Object proxy, java.lang.reflect.Method method, Object[] args) throws java.lang.Throwable {
    log("methodName", method.getName());
    return 1;
}
```

And now it works... Meanwhile both methods of this interface are void. What is happenning here?

Comment: Why do you need to define the ServiceConnection using reflection?

Comment: For security reasons, in order to make the code obfuscated and harder to detect.

Comment: it works just fine: this is my logcat output: `MainActivity  D  invoke public native int java.lang.Object.hashCode()

           MainActivity  D  invoke public abstract void android.content.ServiceConnection.onServiceConnected(android.cont`

Comment: I'm no security expert but can't you still detect anonymous classes at run time? The code won't be in the .class files but I would think you can still inspect the code using reflection. Also you'd still have to place the logic you'd normally put in onServiceConnected/onServiceDisconnected inside of  invoke which seems to me like it defeats the purpose.

Comment: well that was my requirement and not my decision...of course the method names would be scrambeld/unscrambled on runtime and bindService will be called with reflection too. If you have a better idea i'd be glad to hear it. But the problem I mentioned still remains

Comment: no problems remains: `Proxy` works just fine, see my output above

Comment: but actually, why dont you protect your service with some permission? for example signature permission? or runtime checks inside `Binder#onTransact` method?

Comment: @pskink I'm sorry but what output are you reffering to? It's not my own service. It's InAppBillingService from the Android billing library

Comment: @Anonymous check the return value of bindService. Maybe it is returning false because it failed to make a connection. Also, try adding this line to your binding call, "serviceIntent.setPackage("com.android.vending");". Maybe without that call, the system implicitly fails.

Comment: I mean their return type is void. So it doesn't make sense that my code worked after returning 1 on invoke;

Comment: `int java.lang.Object.hashCode()` is not void - it returns `int`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the invoke method returned null. Apparently in the system methods at some point the hashCode() method was called and the null value was a problem.

```
ServiceConnection mServiceConnection = (ServiceConnection) java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(
ServiceConnection.class.getClassLoader(),
new java.lang.Class[] { ServiceConnection.class },
new java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler() {

    @Override
    public Object invoke(Object proxy, java.lang.reflect.Method method, Object[] args) throws java.lang.Throwable {
        log("methodName", method.getName());
        return 1;
    }
});
```

This way it works fine.